# Problema en la llamada a funciones en Python 3

Tags: python, python-3.x, algoritmos

tengo un código en python 3 y me da errores en las llamadas a métodos definidos.

**Mi código:**

```
import hormiga
import tareas
class Colonia:
    def __init__ (self, tareas, n_iteraciones, evaporacion=0.1, n_hormigas=20):
        self.__constanteEvaporacion = evaporacion
        self.__nHormigas = n_hormigas
        self.__iteraciones = n_iteraciones
        self.__evaporacion = 1.0 - evaporacion
        self.__tareas = tareas

        self.__mejorCoste = float('inf')
        self.__mejorRuta = list()
        self.__hormigas = []
        #inicializamos matriz de feromonas
        self.__T = 1 # TEDD
        self.__sortedList = sorted(self.__tareas, key=lambda tarea: tarea.getTiempo())
        for tarea in self.__sortedList: #EDD
            self.__T += tarea.getTiempo() #EDD
        self.__mFeromonas = [[1/(self.__nHormigas * self.__T)]*len(self.__tareas) for x in range(len(self.__tareas))]
        self.__feromonas = [[0.0]*len(self.__tareas) for x in range(len(self.__tareas))]


    #getters y setters
    def getConstanteEvaporacion(self):
        return self.__constanteEvaporacion
    def setConstanteEvaporacion(self,nuevo):
        self.__constanteEvaporacion = nuevo
    def getNumeroHormigas(self):
        return self.__nHormigas
    def setNumeroHormigas(self,nuevo):
        self.__nHormigas = nuevo
    def getNumeroIteraciones(self):
        return self.__iteraciones
    def setNumeroIteraciones(self,nuevo):
        self.__iteraciones = nuevo
    def getEvaporacion(self):
        return self.__evaporacion
    def setEvaporacion(self,nuevo):
        self.__evaporacion = nuevo
    def getTareas(self):
        return self.__tareas
    def setTareas(self,nuevo):
        self.__tareas = nuevo
    def getMejorCoste(self):
        return self.__mejorCoste
    def setMejorCoste(self,nuevo):
        self.__mejorCoste = nuevo
    def getMejorRuta(self):
        return self.__mejorRuta
    def setMejorRuta(self,nuevo):
        self.__mejorRuta = nuevo
    def getHormigas(self):
        return self.__hormigas
    def setHormigas(self,nuevo):
        self.__hormigas = nuevo
    def getMatrizFeromonas(self):
        return self.__mFeromonas
    def setMatrizFeromonas(self,nuevo):
        self.__mFeromonas = nuevo
    def getFeromonas(self):
        return self.__feromonas
    def set(self,nuevo):
        self.__feromonas = nuevo

    def limpiaFeromonas(self):
        for i in range(len(getTareas())):
            for j in range(len(getTareas())):
                self.__feromonas[i][j] = 0.0

    def crearHormigas(self, colonia):
        for numero in range(getNumeroHormigas()):
            ant = hormiga.Hormiga(colonia)
            self.__hormigas.append(ant)

    def getValorInicialFeromona(self): ##VALOR INICIAL FEROMONA: PAGINA 3 TAU0
        return 1/(getNumeroHormigas() * getTEDD())

    def getTEDD(self):
        T = 0
        for tarea in self.__sortedList:
            T += tarea.getTiempo()
        return T

    def enviarHormigas(self):
        for hormiguita in getHormigas():
            if (hormiguita.getCoste() < getMejorCoste()):
                setMejorCoste(hormiguita.getCoste())
                for tarea in hormiguira.getRuta():
                    self.__mejorRuta.append(tarea)
            feromonaHormiga = 1.0 / hormiguita.getCoste()
            for pos in range(len(getTareas())):
                self.__feromonas[pos][hormiguita.getRuta(pos)] = feromonaHormiga

    def actualizaFeromonas(self):
        for i in range(len(getTareas())):
            for j in range(len(getTareas())):
                self.__mFeromonas[i][j] = self.__mFeromonas[i][j] * getEvaporacion() + getConstanteEvaporacion() * getValorInicialFeromona() #NUEVA FORMULA DE FEROMONA DADA EN EL ESTUDIO CIENTÍFICO

    def empezar(self):
        for e in range(self.__iteraciones):
            limpiaFeromonas()
            enviarHormigas()
            actualizaFeromonas()
```

El error es en el método empezar, dice que no existe las funciones `limpiaFeromonas()` ni las otras dos.

```
    def empezar(self):
        for e in range(self.__iteraciones):
            limpiaFeromonas()
            enviarHormigas()
            actualizaFeromonas()
```

He probado a meter el código directamente en vez de llamar a la función, pero me da error diciendo que otra función (definida en los getters) no existe, así que he supuesto que tiene que ser algún problema más grande, no solo de la función empezar en concreto.

¿Alguna idea?

**Gracias**

Comment: Te has olvidado de la instancia al llamar a los métodos,  son métodos de instancia por lo tanto debes llamarlos: `self.limpiaFeromonas()`, `self.enviarHormigas()` y `self.actualizaFeromonas()`. Te recomiendo que en vez de setters y getters uses [properties](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/functions.html#property). Un saludo.

Comment: No sabía todo eso, muchas gracias!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Para hacer referencia a una método/variable de una misma instancia dentro de una clase debes usar self. (así como usarías objeto. al hacer referencia a un método/variable de otra instancia), tu código quedaría (me tomé la libertad de agregar la línea "# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-" puesto que recibía el error "*SyntaxError: Non-ASCII character '\xc3' in file stack03.py on line 98, but no encoding declared; see http://python.org/dev/peps/pep-0263/ for details*"):

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

import hormiga
import tareas

class Colonia:
    def __init__ (self, tareas, n_iteraciones, evaporacion=0.1, n_hormigas=20):
        self.__constanteEvaporacion = evaporacion
        self.__nHormigas = n_hormigas
        self.__iteraciones = n_iteraciones
        self.__evaporacion = 1.0 - evaporacion
        self.__tareas = tareas

        self.__mejorCoste = float('inf')
        self.__mejorRuta = list()
        self.__hormigas = []
        #inicializamos matriz de feromonas
        self.__T = 1 # TEDD
        self.__sortedList = sorted(self.__tareas, key=lambda tarea: tarea.getTiempo())
        for tarea in self.__sortedList: #EDD
            self.__T += tarea.getTiempo() #EDD
        self.__mFeromonas = [[1/(self.__nHormigas * self.__T)]*len(self.__tareas) for x in range(len(self.__tareas))]
        self.__feromonas = [[0.0]*len(self.__tareas) for x in range(len(self.__tareas))]

    #getters y setters
    def getConstanteEvaporacion(self):
        return self.__constanteEvaporacion
    def setConstanteEvaporacion(self,nuevo):
        self.__constanteEvaporacion = nuevo
    def getNumeroHormigas(self):
        return self.__nHormigas
    def setNumeroHormigas(self,nuevo):
        self.__nHormigas = nuevo
    def getNumeroIteraciones(self):
        return self.__iteraciones
    def setNumeroIteraciones(self,nuevo):
        self.__iteraciones = nuevo
    def getEvaporacion(self):
        return self.__evaporacion
    def setEvaporacion(self,nuevo):
        self.__evaporacion = nuevo
    def getTareas(self):
        return self.__tareas
    def setTareas(self,nuevo):
        self.__tareas = nuevo
    def getMejorCoste(self):
        return self.__mejorCoste
    def setMejorCoste(self,nuevo):
        self.__mejorCoste = nuevo
    def getMejorRuta(self):
        return self.__mejorRuta
    def setMejorRuta(self,nuevo):
        self.__mejorRuta = nuevo
    def getHormigas(self):
        return self.__hormigas
    def setHormigas(self,nuevo):
        self.__hormigas = nuevo
    def getMatrizFeromonas(self):
        return self.__mFeromonas
    def setMatrizFeromonas(self,nuevo):
        self.__mFeromonas = nuevo
    def getFeromonas(self):
        return self.__feromonas
    def set(self,nuevo):
        self.__feromonas = nuevo

    def limpiaFeromonas(self):
        for i in range(len(self.getTareas())):
            for j in range(len(self.getTareas())):
                self.__feromonas[i][j] = 0.0

    def crearHormigas(self, colonia):
        for numero in range(self.getNumeroHormigas()):
            ant = hormiga.Hormiga(colonia)
            self.__hormigas.append(ant)

    def getValorInicialFeromona(self): ##VALOR INICIAL FEROMONA: PAGINA 3 TAU0
        return 1/(self.getNumeroHormigas() * getTEDD())

    def getTEDD(self):
        T = 0
        for tarea in self.__sortedList:
            T += tarea.getTiempo()
        return T

    def enviarHormigas(self):
        for hormiguita in self.getHormigas():
            if (hormiguita.getCoste() < self.getMejorCoste()):
                self.setMejorCoste(hormiguita.getCoste())
                for tarea in hormiguira.getRuta():
                    self.__mejorRuta.append(tarea)
            feromonaHormiga = 1.0 / hormiguita.getCoste()
            for pos in range(len(self.getTareas())):
                self.__feromonas[pos][hormiguita.getRuta(pos)] = feromonaHormiga

    def actualizaFeromonas(self):
        for i in range(len(self.getTareas())):
            for j in range(len(self.getTareas())):
                self.__mFeromonas[i][j] = self.__mFeromonas[i][j] * self.getEvaporacion() + self.getConstanteEvaporacion() * getValorInicialFeromona() #NUEVA FORMULA DE FEROMONA DADA EN EL ESTUDIO CIENTÍFICO

    def empezar(self):
        for e in range(self.__iteraciones):
            self.limpiaFeromonas()
            self.enviarHormigas()
            self.actualizaFeromonas()
```